# Regex to match non-spaced phrase with spaced-phrase

Tags: regex

A few examples:

- "ilikestackoverflow" would match "i like stackoverflow"
- "thisisanotherexample" would match "this is another example"

I realize I could remove the spaces on the right hand to match the left hand, but I would save significant space and processing time by being able to go from left to right.

Comment: How would using a regex save you space or time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would only be quicker to remove the spaces on the right side than having the regex parser (something like a state machine) trying every single combination and backtracing everytime.

Does `A BC` match `ABC`?

The regexp could be `^A\s?B\s?C$`

1. Do I have an A first? **yes** go on
2. Do I have a space? **yes** go on
3. Do I have a B? **yes** go on
4. Do I have a space? **no** skip (because of the `?` meaning 0 or 1)
5. Do I have a C? **yes** go on
6. Am I at the end of the string? **yes** where are done here.

Comparing two strings is much, much lighter and will be faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
var spaced = 'i like stack over flow';
var nonSpaced = 'ilikestackoverflow';

console.log(spaced.split(' ').join('') == nonSpaced); // true
```

Use `split(' ').join('')` when you want to replace basic things. In this case there is no need to use RegEx, this will perform much better than a Regex.